# What would the security concerns be impleting this 2FA method?

Tags: authentication, security

What are the security concerns with implementing this type of 2 Factor Authentication?
Using latest MySQLi & PHP.

Steps for each sign-in occurrence after initial account set-up:

1. Sign page form contains only email address field (proper format validated).
2. Script checks for email address in DB.
3. If email found, script generates 32bit unique id number and populates column in same table that has email address.
4. Script generates an email to user with unique id embedded in link.
5. User receives email and clicks link.
6. Script receives the unique id, matches it, and retrieves email address and password, deletes unique id and opens 2nd sign in page with password field.
7. User inputs password, then pass/fail test.
8. If fail, user can try 2 more times. If fail then goes back to Step 1
9. Upon returning to Step 1 after 3 failed attempts, link to reset password is provided.
10. Password reset form requirements are similar using unique id sent to email.

This has not yet been implemented... seeking advice.

This works in practice.  Looking for missed security holes.

Comment: This is ok, but not 2FA. Multiple factors should be different across something you know (a password or email account access), something you have (a token or device) and something you are (biometrics).